# Не удается получить информацию о покупке

Tags: php

Использую web-сервер в качестве бэкэнда приложения android.
При попытке получить информацию о покупке в приложении (для подтверждения платежа) через метод purchases.products: get, то получаю ошибку: The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation.(Code 401)

Авторизация происходит через сервисный аккаунт, созданный в https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials
Это приложение прилинковано к аккаунту в https://play.google.com/apps/publish/
И выданы разрешения для "Просмотр финансовых данных"

Со стороны сервера я могу получить список "inappproducts", но не могу получить информацию о покупке.
Пробовал выдавать права "Администратор", не помогло.
Подскажите пожалуйста, что я упустил?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была решена.
Вероятней всего, ошибка была в том, что в качестве примера покупки для тестирования была использована покупка, оформленная не в актуальной версии приложения.